# The Elm / functional way of passing props to components

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, elm

I'm new to Elm and functional programming. I'm building an expense tracking app which has a model like this:

```
initialModel =
    { expenseTransactions =
        [ { date = Date.fromString "2016/10/23"
          , transactions =
              [ { id = 1
                  , amount = 17.54
                  , description = "stuff"
                  , category = 3
                  }
                , { id = 2
                  , amount = 15.0
                  , description = "things"
                  , category = 4
                  }
              ]
          }
      ],
      expenseCategories =
        Dict.fromList [ ( 1, "Rent" ), ( 2, "Groceries" ), ( 3, "Eating out" ) ]
    }
```

In my view, I'm using a `renderExpensesTable` function, which in turn calls a `renderExpensesForOneDay` function, which in turns calls a `renderExpensesRow` function.

What I want to do is keep storing the transaction's `category` as a number, and then  reference its name from the view by doing something that would look like `expenseCategories[transaction.category]` in other languages. (I get that if I just stored the category as a string like `"Groceries"` this problem would be moot, but the reason I want to store the `category` as a number in the model and then reference it separately is that the user will be able to edit category names, and I don't want to have to update every single transaction in the model every time that happens, which I would have to do if I stored the `category` as a string.)

I've realised I have to pass `expenseCategories` from the `view` method down through each level (`renderExpensesTable`, `renderExpensesForOneDay`, etc.).

```
renderExpenseRow : ExpenseTransaction -> List String -> Html msg
renderExpenseRow transaction categories =
    -- ... row stuff ...

renderExpensesForOneDay : ExpensesForOneDay -> List String -> Html msg
renderExpensesForOneDay day categories =
    let
        dayTransactions =
            List.map2 renderExpenseRow day.transactions categories
    in
        -- ... yada yada ...
        dayTransactions

renderExpensesTable : List ExpensesForOneDay -> List String -> Html msg
renderExpensesTable days categories =
    let
        renderedDays =
            List.map2 renderExpensesForOneDay days (Dict.values categories)
    in
        div [ class "expenses-table" ] renderedDays
```

This doesn't work, and I think it's because I probably shouldn't be trying to use `List.map2` for this. I was succeeding with `map` before I tried to pass in the categories, and this is my attempt to pass them in along with the other stuff (like props in React).

What's the ideal "Elm way" to do this kind of thing? If we can't access the model directly, and we don't have React-style props, how should we deal with situations where there are two different bits of the model that we want to reference like `expenseTransactions` and `expenseCategories`?

Comment: BTW, the type definitions of your render functions are incorrect. They should take a dict, not list, as their second argument.

Comment: I originally did that, but then I intentionally used a list because I couldn't pass both a list and a dict to any of the `map` functions. They only ever accept one type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store your separate categories structure in the selfsame model?

Something like:

```elm
type Model = 
  Model { expenseTransactions: tl
        , expenseCategories: Dict.fromList [ ( 1, "Rent" ), ( 2, "Groceries" ), ( 3, "Eating out" ) ] }
```

Finally all your view functions would take this mega model:

```elm
viewWhatever : Model -> Html Msg
viewWhatever = ...
```

> I still don't get how to pass the model through. Each render function connects to the next via a List.map, and since that only takes lists as arguments, how could the model be passed through

You can modify those render functions to take the model as their first argument. For example:

```elm
renderExpensesForOneDay : Model -> ExpensesForOneDay -> List String -> Html msg
...

renderExpensesTable : Model -> List ExpensesForOneDay -> List String -> Html msg
...
      List.map2 (renderExpensesForOneDay model) days (Dict.values categories)
```

Note above how in that last sentence we pass a curried function (`renderExpensesForOneDay model`) to List.map2.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure this is answering the question, although I may just not realise it yet because I'm a beginner and I don't understand your answer at all. I should have been clearer: I'm not looking for a way to change the model; I just want to show information from the model in the views. When that information comes from one place in the model like `expenseTransactions`, it's simple because I can pass it through as an argument, but when it comes from two places (like `expenseTransactions` and `expenseCategories`) I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was actually already putting them in the same model, hopefully that's clearer in the original post after my edit. My problem is that I don't know how to pass both bits of the model down through the 3 layers of components while successfully using things like `List.map`.

Comment: @sebu - What about passing the entire model to each of your render (view) functions? Otherwise, I'm not exactly clear what you are actually asking.

Comment: OK, now we're on the same page :) I guess I could do that – I think I just assumed it was bad practice because it would involve passing through a huge amount of unnecessary information (there will be other stuff in there like income transactions that have nothing to do with the `expenses` table). Is that the "best practice" way to do it? Or maybe there's no other way to do it...?

Comment: [The Elm Architecure](http://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/) recommends that you represent the entire state of your application in a single model. Performance should not be significantly affected due to the use of [immutable data structures](http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/0.12.1).

Comment: After trying this, I still don't get how to pass the model through. Each render function connects to the next via a `List.map`, and since that only takes lists as arguments, how could the model be passed through?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the recommended practice :) Just saw that.

Comment: @sebu - Easy, you pass the model as the first argument to all render functions. See my update to the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127474/discussion-between-sridhar-ratnakumar-and-sebu).